# Is it on purpose to show Hayley's brother's back in Snatchers?

Tags: snatchers

In [Snatchers](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/snatchers) (2019), around 1:10:00, when Sara and Hayley are researching on Skyler's video log, Hayley's brother is standing in the scene, back to the camera and is out of focus. This was very creepy since I forgot that Hayley's brother is there and didn't know who was that. Did the film do this on purpose?